# passing more than one variable using href in php

Tags: php

Am trying to send 2 variables from one page to another but in url i can see only one variable when i use &, but if i use ',' both variables are appear in thew url but in 2nd page if i tried to get the variables using $_GET[testid] both variables display,how to access 2 variables differently in 2nd page?

```
echo "<tr><td align=center ><a href=quiz.php?testid=$x[0]&subid=$x[3]><font size=4>$x[2]</font></a>";
```

in second page i use this code

```
$a=$_GET['subid'];
$b=$_GET['testid'];
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

the url in the next page

http://localhost/online/quiz.php?testid=187

Comment: Can you copy here the URL? Maybe something is missing from your `x` array.

Comment: Use curly braces: `?testid={$x[0]}&` etc...

Comment: If you are looking to keep what you have, PHP has *[complex curly syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)* where you can do double quotes so: `"testid={$x[0]}"` in combination with escaped quotes: `"<a href=\"quiz.php?testid={$x[0]}\">"`

Comment: @AbraCadaver we were thinking along the same lines...

Answer (score 1):

It all gets a bit complicated when you have to use both single and double quotes

This should produce what you want

```
echo '<tr><td align="center"><a href="quiz.php?testid=' . $x[0] . '&subid=' . $x[3] . '"><font size="4">' . $x[2] . '</font></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr><td align=center >
<a href='quiz.php?testid=".$x[0]."&subid=".$x[3]."'>
  <font size=4>$x[2]</font>
</a>";
```